# what encoding should I use to open a file with a big letter N with tilde character?

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to open a file with a big letter N tilde (http://graphemica.com/%C3%91) but I can't seem to figure it out. when I open the file in notepad++ it shows the character as xD1, when I open the file in gedit it shows \D1. When I open the file in excel, it shows the character correctly.

Now I'm trying to open the file in python, it halts when it encounters the character. I'm aware that I can put in the encoding so the file can be opened properly but I'm not sure which encoding I should use. My error is

**UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 0: invalid continuation byte**

this is my code

```
with codecs.open('tsv.txt', 'r', 'utf8') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        print(line)
```

if it is not utf8, then what should I use? From the site above, it does not show which encoding 0xd1 is associated with.

Comment: Did you mean to use `utf-8` instead of `utf8`?

Comment: That would be latin1, not utf8.

Comment: The only correct encoding is the one the author chose. Ask, or listen—perhaps to the HTTP Content-Type header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find in tables how 'Ñ' gets encoded in different encodings.

You can also try it directly with Python:

```
>>> 'Ñ'.encode('utf8')
b'\xc3\x91'
>>> 'Ñ'.encode('latin1')
b'\xd1'
```

It seems that your file is encoded in latin-1.